# Disable Material-UI production css classnames in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI for React and I'd like to disable the way it handles the classnames when `NODE_ENV=production`. For example

- development: .MuiAppBar-root-12
- production: .jss12

I'd like the production class names to be the same classes used in development (I'm using this framework for prototyping reasons and it's hard to debug when sharing to others).

Comment: What are you using to minify your CSS?

Comment: I'm just using create-react-app's default `npm run build` task

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

As implied by the prod prefix `.jss12`, Material UI uses `react-jss` to perform this minification.  You can use Material UI's `createGenerateClassName` helper and turn on `dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS`, or simply create your own `generateClassName` function and pass it to a wrapping `JssProvider` component.

From the [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/):

```
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS: true, // won't minify CSS classnames when true
  productionPrefix: 'c', // 'jss' by default
});

function App() {
  return (
    <JssProvider generateClassName={ generateClassName }>
      ...
    </JssProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Alternatively, if you want something more powerful (e.g. regexp matching), you can simply define your own function, as in [this example on Github](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1782).

Example:

```
let classNameIndex = 0;
const generateClassName = (rule, styleSheet) => {
  classNameIndex++;
  return `${ styleSheet.options.classNamePrefix }-${ rule.key }-${ classNameIndex }`;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work with material-ui v5 anymore

Answer (score 2):

Adding `index: 1` as the second argument of `makeStyles` function. See [MuiOptions](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook).

Also: [createStyleSheet](https://cssinjs.org/jss-api/?v=v10.7.1#create-style-sheet)

> index - 0 by default - determines DOM rendering order, higher number = higher specificity (inserted after).

```js
//Do This Where ever you used 
//withStyle or makeStyle 
                                                                               
import { makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";                           
                                                                                   
  makeStyles((theme) => ({                                         
     root: {                                                                       
       flexGrow: 1,                                                                
     },                                                                            
     demo: {                                                                       
       backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,                            
       marginBottom: 40,                                                           
     },                                                                            
    title: {                                                                      
      margin: theme.spacing(4, 0, 2),                                             
    },                                                                            
  }), { index : 1 });
```

[image]